# Statistical model for likelihood that an athlete will "place" in track and field

Tags: regression, probability, distributions, ranking

I'm trying to come up with some sort of statistical model to predict how likely an athlete would be to place in a track and field event (e.g. 100m run) based on their time. I was thinking it would be more simple just to predict that they place (i.e. typically top 3) rather than predicting an actual place. For example, if an athlete runs 100m in 10 seconds, they are very likely to place. If they run it in 20s, they are very unlikely to place.

I tried a couple simple regressions predicting a simple 1 vs. 0 (placed vs. didn't place) value; but the results were not very good. I was also thinking I could manually choose z-scores from the population where placing was very unlikely vs. very likely, and just interpolate between those; but that doesn't seem very precise. There must be some better way to do this; but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Are you talking about time vs. rank in the _same_ race? In that case you're measuring the same outcome just on a different scale.

Comment: No, across many races worth of data. For a given level of competition, I want to be able to predict the likelihood that a given time if good enough to place in some future race.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the simpler version

> I was thinking it would be more simple just to predict that they place (i.e. typically top 3) rather than predicting an actual place.

you could take the proposed new time and find the probability this time would place top 3 or not through your available race data. For example, the proposed 100m time is 10.25s and looking at the historical race data you may find they would place top 3 in 45% of races. This could be the prediction that this time finishes top 3 in a future race.

To answer the fuller question,

> I'm trying to come up with some sort of statistical model to predict how likely an athlete would be to place in a track and field event (e.g. 100m run) based on their time.

of where would the time place in the race you could use [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression); this is a type of regression model that is used when there is some ordering to the response variable.

You don't say exactly what data you have available

> No, across many races worth of data

but there are a number of variables that likely influence the race position of a time in a given 100m race, such as wind direction, wind speed, calibre of competitors, elevation of the track etc. I would expect these variables are very important to the placement a given time would receive in a competitive race. If you could get hold of this additional race data you would likely be able to make more accurate predictions.

Answer (score 1):

As potential factors involved I am thinking of

- variations in the season because athletes follow some schedule
- variations in these variations because athletes may have different schedules
- noise because athletes performance is influenced by external factors (little colds, stress, upset stomach, not enough sleep the last weeks, etc)
- trends for different athletes
- variations in the field of competitors

  (e.g. the last world chess champion had an ELO rating of 2780, which is less than the champion of the past years, but that is since the champion of the past years, Magnus Carlsen, has stopped competing)
- personal development

What you could do is model all these elements, and fit them. Then make the predictions with that model.

I guess that the easiest would be to

1. start modelling the times of individuals, 1a) how they develop and 1b) vary throughout the season, 1c) possibly detect some clusters like different styles of athletes in how they vary and develop.
2. Then model the probability to encounter particular opponents of a specific kaliber for some competition.
3. Then based on performance distributions compute the probability for an individual to win. (This might be done with simulations)

---

Or speaking about easy, if you just need a ballpark estimate, you can plot distributions of the winning time over the past years for different types of competions (which you could match based on some measure for similarity). Then use those distributions to make an estimate about the probability that some athlete can achieve the winning time.